# How to get difference in hours between two timestamp columns in pandas data-frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I am trying to get time difference between start and end timestamp data given in '%H:%M:%S.%f' format but getting value error

```
Data-
|Start time|End time |
|----------|---------|
|02:48:00  | 03:03:00|
|02:48:00  | 03:03:00|
|22:21:00  | 23:40:00|
|22:21:00  | 23:40:00|
|01:30:00  | 02:54:00|
|09:10:00  | 10:13:00|
|05:31:00  | 06:28:00|
|23:09:00  | -1|
|16:09:00  | 17:29:00|
```

code I am trying

```
df3['timespent'] = pd.to_datetime(str(df3['End time'])) - pd.to_datetime(str(df3['Start Time']))
```

Error-

```
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '0     03:03:00\n1     03:03:00\n2     23:40:00\n3     23:40:00\n4     02:54:00\n        ...   \n86    21:13:00\n87    14:24:00\n88    19:57:00\n89    22:23:00\n90    10:53:00\nName: End time, Length: 91, dtype: object')*
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to strip out the spaces if the values are already in a `DataFrame` -

```
pd.to_datetime(df3['End time'].str.strip()) - pd.to_datetime(df3['Start Time'].str.strip())
```

If the format is not automatically recognized - you can pass in a format string to the `to_datetime` function

Comment: Hi Mortz, I used your code but received error- Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: though the format of start and end time is in object/str format only

Comment: Where you get the error - print out the value of `df3.dtypes`

Comment: datatypes shown: Start Time- object, End time - object, dtype: object

Comment: Is this error due to outlier (-1) in End time column?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, seeing your data, I would recommend to apply `pd.to_timedelta`. These can be used to calculate the Timedelta between the start and end and then finallly access the `seconds` field of the time.

Having said that, your string will probably need some stripping `.strip()` in order to get the format shown below in the code.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'start' : ["20:15:12", "08:08:08", "23:59:58"], 
    'end' : ["20:25:52", "11:11:11", "00:01:01"]
})


# convert 'start' and 'end' to timedeltas and then substract start from end
df['diff'] = df.apply(pd.to_timedelta).apply(lambda x: x.end - x.start,axis=1)
# correct those that cross midnight
correct24h = timedelta(hours=24)
df['diff'] = df['diff'].apply(lambda x: x + correct24h if x.delta < 0 else x)

# calculate hours from seconds
df['diff_hours'] = df['diff'].dt.seconds / 60 / 60

df
      start       end            diff  diff_hours
0  20:15:12  20:25:52 0 days 00:10:40    0.177778
1  08:08:08  11:11:11 0 days 03:03:03    3.050833
2  23:59:58  00:01:01 0 days 00:01:03    0.017500
```

Comment: Looking again at the other answer and the discussion - your problem is more of a how did you read the data and construct the data frame problem. Is it coming from a file? how does it look like?

Comment: Its from excel file I imported, given in hours and seconds format 'hh:ss'

Comment: Some example code would go to great lengths. E.g. how is your import statemen? Also, the data example you posted is not an python output statement I guess.

Comment: I have daywise excel files for week, so i appended all excel files in one usin code- all_data = []
for f in glob.glob("...path.../*.xlsx"):
    all_data.append(pd.read_excel(f)) df1 = pd.concat(all_data, ignore_index=True)